# What does this regex/re-write do?

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

In the following code, what does the regex do?

```
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}       ^/(?:[A-Za-z]+(?:/[A-Za-z]*)*)(?:/\d+)?$
RewriteRule   .*                   var/www/%1/index.php [L]
```

What is the outcome of the re-wrtie rule?

Thanks, I am helping a friend fix an old CMS and I don't know why whomever made it did this.

Comment: There are many issues with this code, better to spell out your requirement and get help here on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the outcome of the re-write rule?

AFAIK it will generate 404s when you don't expect it to.  Why?

1. The (?: something) brackets are basically the same as () except that they don't set a match variable. Since all bracketing is like this `%1` will never be defined.
2. Picking up Alexander's description `/letters{/letters}([/digits])` where the `/digits` are optional.  The repeat group is "zero or more letters" and hence will eat any **`/`** characters, and these are greedy matches, so `/aa/bb/cc/123` will be parsed as  (`/aa`)(`/bb`)(`/cc`)(`/`)(`123`).  This will fail since **123** does not match `(?:/\d+)?`
3. So it will only match alpha path strings, e.g. /aaa/bbb/ccc and %1 will be "" and in these circumstances this will redirect to `var/www//index.php` relative to the current path, which will probably be the DOCROOT, so unless `DOCROOT/var/www/index.php` exists, this will result in a 404.

Answer (score 2):

It is supposed to redirect all requests of the form `/letters{/letters}[/digits]` to a local file `var/www/SOMETHING/index.php` but it does not: first, there is no capturing group (all groups have leading `?:` and, consequently, it is not clear what `SOMETHING` will be). Next, the `var/www...` part should perhaps have a leading `/`.

Comment: To clarify, `{...}` means _zero or more times_, `[...]` means _zero or one time_.

Answer (score 0):

Following the [mod-rewrite help](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), the `%1` should refer to the first capturing group of the regexp from the last RewriteCond. *But* the regexp only has non-capturing groups...